# Why are shell variables invisible in my Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, bash

Working with Ruby shell executions by a backquote or `%x` syntax I found that when I declare a new variable in bash it is not visible by ruby script, until I make it environment by `export` command.

Please explain mechanism why do Shell Variables is not visible by a script?

```
# Shell and Environment variables.
V123='This is an variable. VAR HERE.'
echo $V123

# Read shell variable via Ruby
ruby -e 'p `echo $V123`' # "$V123\n"
ruby -e 'p %x[echo $V123]' # "$V123\n"

# Check SET for this var
set | grep V123
ruby -e 'p `set | grep V123`' # ""
ruby -e 'p %x[set | grep V123]' # ""

# Put this var itno the Environment
echo "--- Export"
printenv V123
export V123
printenv V123
echo "--- Ruby printenv"
ruby -e 'p `printenv V123`' # This is an variable. VAR HERE.\n"
ruby -e 'p %x[printenv V123]' # This is an variable. VAR HERE.\n"
```

Comment: This might help: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: Why do you expect the subshell to derive the environment of the parent shell in the first place? That’s not how bash works. One might `V123=FOO ruby -e 'p \`echo $V123\`'` to explicitly pass the env var to another shell script. **Sidenote:** that behaviour has nothing to do with ruby, it’s shell subprocess default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question does not *really* have anything to do with ruby; it's just about the behaviour of bash variables.

> I found that when I declare a new variable in bash it is not visible by ruby script, until I make it environment by `export` command.

Sub-shells do not inherit the environment of their parent shell. You can explicitly call a sub-shell with variables, or you can `export` them. (That's the *whole point* of the `export` function!)

For example, consider the following - which, again, has got nothing to do with ruby.

Suppose `test.txt` has the following lines:

```
line one
line two
```

Observe the following outputs:

1. When the variable is declared as a separate command, it is **not** passed to the sub-shell:

   ```
   GREP_OPTIONS='-v'
   grep one test.txt

   // Result:
   line one
   ```
2. When the variable is set as part of the same command, it **is** passed to the sub-shell:

   ```
   GREP_OPTIONS='-v' grep one test.txt

   // Result:
   line two
   ```
3. When the variable is **exported**, it **is** passed to the sub-shell:

   ```
   export GREP_OPTIONS='-v'
   grep one test.txt

   // Result:
   line two
   ```